# Reset all graphs in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Is there a way to reset all tensorflow graphs?**

I am running a hyperparamter search for a convolutional neural network in tensorflow. For each set of hyperparameters I want to build and train the graph similar to how they do it in [this mnist tensorboard tutorilal](https://github.com/dandelionmane/tf-dev-summit-tensorboard-tutorial/blob/master/mnist.py).

The issue is that the `tf.reset_default_graph()` is not sufficient since I have more than one graph.

Comment: You cannot really "reset" a graph in TensorFlow. The only thing that `tf.reset_default_graph` does is resetting the default graph variable to a new graph, but the old graph is not modified (and if you have a reference to it it will still be usable). What you should do is create a new graph each time, either using the default and resetting or with `tf.Graph`.

Comment: Thanks! That resolved my issue.